# Is it polite to refer to someone by the surname in an article?

Tags: names, honorifics

While I see it a lot in articles in the modern time, I remember being taught at school that it is more polite and formal to refer to someone by title and surname in an article, not surname alone. Is that true?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example?

Comment: 'Scott states in the article, that positive reinforcement works exceedingly better and faster than punishment'
vs.
'According to Dr. Scott in his article, positive reinforcement works exceedingly better and faster than punishment'

I see the former more often in articles in the modern time, but remember being taught at school that the latter is more polite.

Other things I was taught include not to use third-person perspective, not use adverb immediately after _to_, etc. These I remember clearly, but the title + surname thing I am not sure.

Comment: Politeness is a matter of opinion, surely? Please put all relevant detail **in the question** (which you can [edit]).

Comment: Various newspapers have style guides that say different things. But I don't know what the modern standard for politeness is - Debretts? Emily Post? What kind of answer do you want?

Comment: It depends on context and the style guide for the publication in question. For instance, I believe the NY Times always refers to people with their title, but other newspapers may have different guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

The only definite answer that can be given to this question is that there is no hard and fast rule about the matter, and that the most prudent thing for a beginning author is to be attentive to, and follow, the practice of the more experienced writers in the same field.

Having said that, there are some definite limits to what is reasonable to do in this respect. When discussing the work of various authors from faraway times or places, last names without titles are practically always used. (Rare exceptions may be the cases in which the title got over time so firmly attached to the name, that it is effectively a part of the name, e.g. *Dr Johnson*.) The idea behind that practice seems to be that any relationship that one may have to such people is entirely impersonal and that in thinking about them we are abstracting from everything about them other than what is embodied in their work. The consequence of thinking about them in that way is that considerations of politeness simply do not come into play.

On the other end of the spectrum, if one is speaking at a conference and discussing the work of a colleague who is present in the room, the considerations of politeness definitely do apply, and one should refer to that colleague in accordance with them, which will usually involve the use of the title (unless, perhaps, it is a very small gathering of people who all know each other well, in which case the use of first names may be OK).

These two limiting case may provide some, albeit imprecise, guidance on what to do in the case that fall between them. Most of the people one refers to in one's academic writing, even if they are one's contemporaries and live in the same country, are people one does not know personally and does not interact with directly. Whatever qualities they may otherwise have, they exist, for the purposes of the writing, solely as the authors of their own published work. In referring to such a person as simply Smith (rather than, say, Professor Smith), one subtly conveys that one is not dealing with Smith as a person, but merely with the content of Smith's article one cites. And sometimes one may choose to do so even if one, in fact, does know Smith personally.

Some academic writing, however, does have the character that resembles direct person-to-person interaction. Building on the second limiting case, above, published proceedings of a conference may convey the flavour of direct discussion that took place there by retaining the way in which the participants referred to each other in the discussion. And some academic writing, even if it has not emerged from live conferences, has the character that resembles person-to-person debates. In such writing it may be appropriate to show respect for one's opponent by following the same norms of politeness as would apply in live discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you used in comments, you might be asking about the usage in academic writing (journal articles, for example).

It's common (nearly universal, in my experience) in academic writing to use a surname without a title.

One reason is that academic papers must be very terse to convey maximum information in minimum column inches.

Another reason is that it is not always easy to know the appropriate academic title for someone you're mentioning. For example, are they a professor or "merely" a doctor without a professorship. Or are you discussing work they did during their Ph.D. work, and therefore they weren't even a doctor at the time.

Of course if there was a tradition of including titles in academic writing, academics would take more care to make their titles known when introducing themselves or presenting papers, so that others could cite them accurately. But that just isn't the tradition that's developed.